# MYSQL / JSON Output Count & Percentages

Tags: php, mysql, json

What I currently have..

**[{"status":"C - Net & Phone","kpi":"Lead","count":"12"}**

What I am trying to do is have it put out
**[{"status":"value","kpi":"value","count":"12""percentage":"%32.42"}**

Here is my php code below.

```
<?php 
        $Connection = mysql_connect('localhost', '', '');
            if (!$Connection) {
                die('ACCESS DENIED' . mysql_error());
        }

        $Database = mysql_select_db('main', $Connection);
            if (!$Database) {
                die ('DIED' . mysql_error());
        }

         $ $query = " SELECT pin_status,kpi_type,COUNT(*) FROM main_pins GROUP BY pin_status;  ";

            $result = mysql_query( $query );
                if ( !$result ) {
                    $ErrorMessage  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
                    $ErrorMessage .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
                die( $ErrorMessage );
        }

        $JSON_output = array();
            while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) )
        {

        $JSON_output[] = array('status'         => $row['pin_status'],
                                'kpi'           => $row['kpi_type'], 
                                'count'         => $row['COUNT(*)'],
                                 'percentage'     => $row[????], // what I would like added
                            );
        }

header( "Content-Type: application/json" );

    $JSON_output = json_encode($JSON_output);

echo $JSON_output . "";

mysql_close($Connection);
?>
```

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Is percentage a column in your table? Or are you trying to calculate a percentage? You also have at least one typo involving a `$`

Comment: I am trying to calculate a percentage. Similar to what I did with the COUNT(*).

Comment: yes I see the $ next to query. That must have been a typo after i put the question together.

Comment: What is the percentage of?

Comment: kpi_type for percent, status for count.

Comment: Percentage of the count of the KPI Type? What is the total?

Comment: Without knowing what the table contains it would be hard to tell you exactly what to do here. You would have to have the total number of KPI type to divide by the count of this particular count to do the percentage, so doing it in the query is not really an option *and may* take two queries - one to get the total KPI and then the query you show here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update your query to look like this.

```
$query = "SELECT pin_status, kpi_type, Count(*) as count,((Count(*)  * 100.0)/ (select Count(*) FROM main_pins)) AS Percentage
                    FROM main_pins
                    GROUP BY pin_status, kpi_type
                    ORDER BY pin_status, kpi_type
                    DESC";
```

add to your JSON output.

```
$JSON_output[] = array('Status'         => $row['pin_status'],
                       'KPI'            => $row['kpi_type'],
                       'Percentage'         => $row['Percentage'],
                       'Count'          => $row['count'],
);}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a column in your database that contains the percentage then all you should do is select that:

```
$query = " SELECT `pin_status`, `kpi_type` ,COUNT(*) AS `current_count`, `percentage` FROM `main_pins` GROUP BY `pin_status`;  ";
```

If you want to calculate something, you have a choice of doing it in the query or in the PHP. For example, in PHP you might do this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result )) {
    $percentage = ($row[$x]/$y) * 100; // supply $x and $y
    $JSON_output[] = array('status'         => $row['pin_status'],
                       'kpi'           => $row['kpi_type'], 
                       'count'         => $row['current_count'],
                       'percentage'     => $percentage
    );
}
```

**As mentioned in comments**

If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: I do not have the column percentage. Simply trying to create a column like I did for count, but display the percentage based off of kpi_type.

Comment: What do you mean supply $x and $y ??

Comment: [{"status":"Sold","kpi":"Sale","count":null,"percentage":0}]  there is several hundred status and kpi types.

Comment: Supply `$x` and `$y` means to provide the data you're using to calculate the percentage @Lzoesch.

Comment: so $x would be kpi_type, and $y would be  deleted ?

Comment: Without seeing your table I cannot tell you if that is correct. Can you edit your original post and add some of your current table information?